# setInterval not calling function

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

```
get_alerts = function(alerts_url) {
    return $.getJSON(alerts_url, function(alerts) {
        return $("#alerts_box").html("" + alerts.length + " Alerts");
    });
};

window.setInterval(function() {
    return get_alerts($("#alerts_box").data("alerts-url"));
}, 1000);
```

If I put a breakpoint in the `setInterval` area, I get notified every second, but the `getJSON` call is never being executed. Looking at my server logs, there is never a request to the `alerts_url`.

**UPDATE**
Appears to be an intermittent Chrome problem.  Fired it up on Safari and it worked as expected.  Clearing out Chrome now and I'll try again.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: @SLaks - I don't see anything related to the JSON call.  Just the requests to get resources for the page load

Comment: @ArrayKnight - Did that work for you? Mine doesn't appear to be loading anything

Comment: @TylerDeWitt not really your issue, but you don't need the return in your setInterval, you can just have the call, get_alerts().

Comment: @ryan - Thanks for the pointer.  It's actuall CoffeeScript that is being converted to javascript, but thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be some sort of caching issue.  I thought Chrome treated all AJAX requests as noncacheable, but I guess not.  Here's the fix:

```
get_alerts = function(alerts_url) {
  var noCache;
  noCache = new Date().getTime();
  return $.getJSON(alerts_url, {
    "cache": noCache
  }, function(alerts) {
    return $("#alerts_box").html("" + alerts.length + " Alerts");
  });
};
```

Sending the `cache` option along with the request seems to fix it.  Apparently, you can also send a random, unique string (like the date/time) as a parameter in the url and that will fix it as well

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok, but what is missing is the initialization of the alerts-url. You did not include that in your code example, so I made a [jsFiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/nhdU8/). Here is the code that worked for me:

```
$("#alerts_box").data("alerts-url","http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:BAUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&maxfeatures=5")

get_alerts = function(alerts_url) {
  $.getJSON(alerts_url, function(alerts) {
    $("#alerts_box").html(new Date().getTime() + " " + alerts.features.length + " Alerts");
  });
};
window.setInterval(function() {
    get_alerts($("#alerts_box").data("alerts-url"));
  }
, 1000);
```